# Differentiating a scalar, product of matrices, with respect matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

Let $\zeta$ be an $n*1$ vector:

$$\zeta=[(GXB)\odot D]l$$
where $G$ is an $n* n$ matrix, $X$ is an $n* k$ matrix, $B$ is a $k* d$ matrix, $D$ an $n* d$ matrix and $l$ a $d*1$ vector

We need to differentiate the scalars $\zeta^T\zeta$ and $\zeta^Ty$ with respect to matrix B ($y$ is an $n*1$ vector).
$$\frac{\partial \zeta^T\zeta}{\partial B}=?$$
$$\frac{\partial \zeta^Ty}{\partial B}=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typing convenience, define
$$\eqalign{
H = GXB,\quad\zeta = (H\odot D)\ell
}$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(AB^T) = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)\\AB:C = B:A^TC = A:CB^T$$

Write the first function in terms of the above, then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \zeta:\zeta \\
d\phi &= 2\zeta:d\zeta \\
 &= 2\zeta:(dH\odot D)\ell \\
 &= 2(\zeta\ell^T\odot D):dH \\
 &= 2(\zeta\ell^T\odot D):GX\,dB \\
 &= 2(GX)^T(\zeta\ell^T\odot D):dB \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B} &= 2X^TG^T(\zeta\ell^T\odot D) \\
}$$
The calculation for the second function is very similar.
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= y:\zeta \\
d\psi &= y:d\zeta \\
 &= y:(dH\odot D)\ell \\
 &= (y\ell^T\odot D):dH \\
 &= (y\ell^T\odot D):GX\,dB \\
 &= (GX)^T(y\ell^T\odot D):dB \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial B} &= X^TG^T(y\ell^T\odot D) \\
}$$